# Existence of convergent sequence in the space of bounded continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ a metric space with metric $d$. Let $B$ be the set of all bounded functions $f:X \to Y$ with the uniform metric. Show that the set of all continuous bounded functions say $CB$ is closed in $B$.

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $CB$ such that $f_n$ converges  to some $f$ in $B$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and choose $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d_\infty(f_{n_0},f)< \varepsilon/3$. From continuity of $f_n$ we also have that $d(x,y) < \delta \implies d(f_{n_0}(x),f_{n_0}(y))< \varepsilon/3$ and now by the triangle inequality we get that $$d(f(x),f(y)) \le \underbrace{d(f(x), f_{n_0}(x))}_{\le d_\infty(f_n,f)} + d(f_{n_0}(x), f_{n_0}(y)) + \underbrace{d(f_{n_0}(y), f(y))}_{\le d_\infty(f_{n_0},f)} < 3\cdot \varepsilon/3 = \varepsilon.$$

This shows that $f$ is continuous which concludes that $CB$ is closed.

> Why can we make such an assumption that there exists $f_n$ in $CB$ that converges to $f$ in $B$?

It seems that we're making assumptions that are not neccessarily true. Is there something fundamental I've missed in my education since I cannot comprehend why such a sequence must exists?

Comment: A subset $S \subseteq X$ is closed iff it contains all of its limit points. In metric spaces, a point $x \in X$ is a limit point of $S$ iff there's a sequence $x_{n} \in S$ that converges to $x$. So you just needed to show that $f \in CB$ whenever such a sequence exists.

Comment: To prove that CB is closed in B you take a sequence in CB converging to some element of B and show that the limit fuction must belong to CB.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the target/goal of your proof of continuity is unclear:

Are you fixing $x$ beforehand to some arbitrary point? Then your argument gives that $f$ is continuous at $x$ when all $f_n$ are. But of course it's invalid because you're using a **metric** on $X$; you have to switch to open neighbourhoods instead,  but that is valid for a fixed $x$ situation and we salvage the proof.

If not, you're assuming that all $f_n$ are *uniformly* continuous (and $X$ metric too) (as your work globally, i.e. for any $x,y$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta$ etc.). In that case your proof will show that $f$ is uniformly continuous when all $f_n$ are. (but you only assume $f_n \in $CB$).

As to your final question:
As $B$ is a metric space we can show a set $CB$ is closed in it by showing it's sequentially closed: **if** there is a sequence $f_n \in A, n \in \Bbb N$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $B$, **then** $f \in A$.

So we have to start the proof of closedness by *assuming* such a sequence in $CB$ to exist, our continuous and bounded $(f_n)$ sequence with $f_n \to f$ with $f \in B$ under the $d_\infty$ metric. Then show that $f \in CB$, which only needs continuity as boundedness of $f$ is assumed/given.

Comment: If I understood you correctly fixing $x$ is related to the metric $d_\infty$? Since every $f_n$ are continuous we have that $d(x,y) < \delta \implies d(f_n(x),f_n(y))< \varepsilon/3$ for every $x,y$.

Comment: @Zwertp No. $x \in X$ and $y$ too, so $d(x,y)$ is not even defined.

Comment: @Zwertp Continuity of $f: X \to Y$ is defined as : $\forall x  \in X:  \forall \varepsilon>0: \exists U \subseteq X \text{ open }: (x \in U) \land \forall y \in U: d(f(x), f(y)) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. We do not have any metric on $X$ so we cannot talk about "distance" there. It seems that then we need to pick open neighborhoods $U$ that contains $x,y$ as you stated.

Comment: @Zwertp  You have to fix $x$ beforehand, then $\varepsilon >0$. You apply the convergence of $f_n \to f$ under $d_\infty$ to $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ to get $N$, and then apply continuity of $f_N$ to $x$ and $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ to get $U$. Then, for this $U$ and all $y \in U$ we can apply the stated inequality and we finally have continuity of $f$ at  $x$ using $U$.